# Set arguments using Android gradle plugin dsl from gradle task

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, annotation-processing

I am working on a gradle plugin for android that has to programmatically set an argument for the annotation processor. `"-AoutputDir=my.path.to.output.dir"`.

So from a gradle plugin `apply()` function I reference all subproject and using the [Android gradle plugin dsl](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/) I tried to set the argument by doing this

```
private fun addAnnotationProcessorOptions(rootProject: Project, outDir: File) {
        rootProject.subprojects {
            it.also { project ->
                project.afterEvaluate {prj->
                    prj.plugins.all { plugin ->
                        when (plugin) {
                            is AppPlugin -> {
                                prj.extensions[AppExtension::class].run {
                                    defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.arguments(
                                            mapOf("outdir" to outDir.absolutePath)
                                    )
                                }
                            }

                            is LibraryPlugin -> {
                                prj.extensions[LibraryExtension::class].run {
                                    defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.arguments(
                                            mapOf("outdir" to outDir.absolutePath)
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

which translates the same as if I was doing this on the build script of each sub-project

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
        //HERE is the same call to the same dsl object
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ['outdir': 'path.to.output']
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to get the argument `outdir` in my annotation processor, this latter throws an exception complaining the the argument `outdir` is not found. However if I set the argument `outdir` from the build script it will pick it up with no problem.

I can't have the argument set from build script as my use-case dictates that this config should be done programmatically.

PS: I used `Project.beforeEvaluate{}`  and `Project.afterEvaluate{}` closures but still no luck.

Any idea about what's going on? Is my dsl config get's overiden? is it possible to set this up via code and not build script?

Thanks in advance.